# How to reset an number input element's value back to its text placeholder using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input element that I would like to reset back to its placeholder value using javascript.

```
<input type="number" placeholder="Number of attempts" id='display'></input>

document.getElementById('display').value = 'Number of attempts'
```

returns an error because the input only accepts numbers

Comment: `returns and error` Works for me, please post a [MCVE] (assigning a non-number will result in the empty string being assigned, I think, which will result in the placeholder being displayed)

Comment: The `input` in your example doesn't have an `id="display"` attribute, so I don't see how that would work? Either way, if you want to restore the placeholder value of a field, you simply need to remove it's value.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Looks like you are correct, but is there any way to complete this problem without having an error pop up in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the *placeholder* property not *value*.

Try the following way:

```js
document.getElementById('display').placeholder = 'Number of attempts'
```

```html
<input type="number" id='display'></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, but the following did:

```js
document.getElementById('display').value = null;
document.getElementById('display').placeholder = 'Number of attempts';
```